# mysql GROUP_CONCAT with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I want to do a group concat with multiple columns inside it.
This is the query I have(I want to know if it is possible, and if not, what other way can I do this?:

```
select  group.groupname, 
        group_concat(machine.machinename,'--',machine.machineModel) 
    inner join etc....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first concatenate those values and then do group_concat.

```
select  group.groupname, 
        group_concat(machine.machinename||'--'||machine.machineModel)) 
    inner join etc....
```

Comment: no such function: concat: select this is the error thar is giving me @Rams

Comment: this is mysqlite, I assume is the same as Mysql

Comment: I have change it to || symbol for concatenation of two values

Comment: Thanks :) great help!